# How to get the actual aspect ratio of the video?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I don't want my video to look stretched. I'm using `Chewie` flutter package as my video player.

I tried using `_controller.value.size.aspectRatio` but it returns an error 
`The getter 'aspectRatio' was called on null.`

here is my code to get a video from gallery:

```
Future uploadVideoFromGallery() async {
    print("CALLED");
    Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions =
        await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions(
            [PermissionGroup.storage, PermissionGroup.camera]);

    if (permissions[PermissionGroup.storage] == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      var videoFile = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (videoFile != null) {
        getVideoThumbnail(videoFile.path);
        setState(() {
          isFileImage = false;
          image = videoFile;
          _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(image);
        });

        print(videoFile.path);
      }
    } else {
      debugPrint('permission not granted');
    }
  }
```

and here is my code to place the `videoFile` :

```
Chewie(
                        controller: ChewieController(
                          videoPlayerController: _controller,
                          aspectRatio: _controller.value.size.aspectRatio,
                          materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
                            playedColor: Color(colorSecondary),
                            handleColor: Color(colorPrimary),
                            bufferedColor: Color(colorPrimary),
                          ),
                          placeholder: Container(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          autoInitialize: true,
                          looping: false,
                          errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
                            return Center(
                              child: Text(
                                errorMessage,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Color(colorText)),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      )
```

Comment: From documentation I just read, it may just be `_controller.value.aspectRatio` instead of `_controller.value.size.aspectRatio`, so try negating the `size` data member.

Comment: This is weird. I tried  `_controller.value.aspectRatio`. It is still stretched after I select a video from my gallery, then tapped fullscreen icon. then tapped it again to close fullscreen. now it shows the actual aspect ratio.

Comment: Can you show the captured screen of your camera?

Comment: we have to wait until it is initialized.

Comment: _controller.value.aspectRatio always returning 1.0 as aspect ratio.

Answer (score 17):

There is an issue on github regarding same.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class MyVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String path;

  MyVideoPlayer({Key key, @required this.path}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyVideoPlayerState createState() => new _MyVideoPlayerState();
}

class _MyVideoPlayerState extends State<MyVideoPlayer> {

  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController _chewieController;
  Future<void> _future;

  Future<void> initVideoPlayer() async {
    await _videoPlayerController.initialize();
    setState(() {
      print(_videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio);
      _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
        aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
        autoPlay: false,
        looping: false,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _controller = VideoPlayerController.network('https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4');
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(widget.path));
    _future = initVideoPlayer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return new Center(
          child: _videoPlayerController.value.initialized
          ? AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
            child: Chewie(
              controller: _chewieController,
            ),
          )
          : new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

[This is the github url](https://github.com/brianegan/chewie/issues/174#issuecomment-519102765)

Comment: always returning 1.0 as aspect ratio.

Comment: This link may be helpful:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/60454576/10187218

Answer (score 8):

If you're just using the regular [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package, you can show an unstretched version of your video using the following code:

```
return FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: model.videoPlayerController.value.size?.height ?? 0,
        width: model.videoPlayerController.value.size?.width ?? 0,
        child: VideoPlayer(model.videoPlayerController),
      ),
    );
```

I wrote an article on [displaying videos from a URL in Flutter](https://jtmuller5-98869.medium.com/displaying-videos-from-a-firebase-cloud-storage-url-828ec27a5ee6), too.

Comment: fit: BoxFit.contain,

Answer (score 8):

better_player plugin solution.

**In initState:**

```
betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(
      betterPlayerConfiguration,
      betterPlayerDataSource: betterPlayerDataSource,
);

betterPlayerController.addEventsListener((BetterPlayerEvent event) {
      if (event.betterPlayerEventType == BetterPlayerEventType.initialized) {
        betterPlayerController.setOverriddenAspectRatio(
            betterPlayerController.videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio);
        setState(() {});
      }
});
```

**In body:**

```
BetterPlayer(controller: betterPlayerController),
```

Comment: Useful in BetterPlayer

Comment: how to use it in BetterPlayer.network()

Comment: Very very useful, nice solution!!!

Comment: I could only make it work with    fullScreenByDefault: false, Wraping the player inside aspect ratio

Comment: @VishweshSoni you Can use BetterPlayerDataSource() method to show which type you want to add like as  _betterPlayerDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
        isNetworks
            ? BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network
            : BetterPlayerDataSourceType.file,
        widget.video);  
& then Pass this _betterPlayerDataSource to    
 _betterPlayerController.setupDataSource(_betterPlayerDataSource);

Answer (score 1):

I only use the aspect ratio from the original videoController and don't set it for Chewie's video controller which works fine for me. To get the aspect ratio, you need to make sure that the original video controller is initialised first, and add a listener with it so that when it calls setState, you widget is rebuilt with the correct aspect ratio video. Meanwhile, you can show a Circular Progress Item until it is not initialized.

This is how I use Chewie with VideoPlayer and the aspect ratio works correctly for me:

```
class _VideoWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  String videoURL;

  _VideoWidget({required this.videoURL});

  @override
  _VideoWidgetState createState() => _VideoWidgetState(videoURL: videoURL);
}

class _VideoWidgetState extends State<_VideoWidget> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Chewie _chewie;
  late ChewieController _chewieController;
  String videoURL;

  _VideoWidgetState({required this.videoURL});


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      videoURL,
      videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true),
    );
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.initialize();
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _controller,
      autoPlay: false,
      looping: false,
    );
    _chewie = Chewie(
      controller: _chewieController,
    );
    _chewieController.addListener(() {
      if (!_chewieController.isFullScreen)
        {
          SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
        }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
          Text("Video",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: _controller.value.isInitialized
                  ? AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: Chewie(
                        controller: _chewieController,
                      ),
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: SizedBox(
                          height: 30.0,
                          width: 30.0,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.blue),
                              strokeWidth: 1.0))),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    return _chewie;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the video player controller is initialised. Assign aspect ratio value to `ChewieController` only after the `_playerController.initialize()` is complete (in the `then` block).

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Uri videoUrl = VideoProvider.fromUri(_post.url).getVideos().first.uri;
    _playerController = VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl.toString());
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _playerController.initialize().then((_) {
      _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _playerController,
        aspectRatio: _playerController.value.aspectRatio,
        allowedScreenSleep: false,
        errorBuilder: (context, error) => Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.error),
            Text(error),
          ],
        )),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _playerController.value.aspectRatio,
            child: Chewie(
              controller: _chewieController,
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try changing `_controller.value.size.aspectRatio` to `_controller.value.aspectRatio`.

Then, make sure that you are initializing the controller using `_controller.initialize()`.

If it stills gives the error, then add a null check.

```
_controller != null
    ? // Do your code
    : Text("Controller is null")
```

This should fix your problem.